# How to declare a class dynamically? C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, anonymous-class

is there any possibility to declare a class dynamically?
is there any possibility to create generic list with anonymous class in C#?
any code snippets will help. thanks

Comment: It's possible, but it's probably  not what you're looking for.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: sorry I was not clear enough. the thing i don't know which properties my class will have. I get the needed properties list dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft made C# dynamic in version 4.0. You can use the new 'dynamic' keyword. The following link has some good examples of how to use the new dynamic type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Declaring a class dynamically requires [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx).

> is there any possibility to create generic list with anonymous class in C#?

Yes, but it's, in general, not recommended for use outside of the immediate context.  For example, this creates a generic list of an anonymous type:

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 100);

var genericList = range.Select(value => new { Value = value }).ToList();
```

In the above code, `genericList` is a `List<T>` containing an anonymous type.

Comment: `CodeDom` is great, but there tends to be a feature disconnect between language features and what `CodeDom` supports (e.g. `readonly` fields).  `System.Reflection.Emit` is the way to go for full control, albeit a more complicated route.

Comment: @Steve: True - but once people understand CodeDom, they can usually find Emit if required...

Answer (score 5):

As SLaks mentioned in the comments, it is possible.  But it is non-trivial.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you can easily add anonymous *types* to a generic list of objects.

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   list.Add(new { SomeProperty = i, OtherProperty = "foobar" });
}
```